# return promises instead of res.json(data) in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal

I do a post request to payment_url which is triggered the second block of function. But I can't get anything in the then method, because I don't know how to pass the data back to the resolve function.

cilent call

```
paypal.request.post(payment_url)
  .then(function(data) {
    resolve(data.paymentID);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    reject(err);
  });
```

server code

```
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function(error, payment) {
  if (error) {
    //throw error, return the promises too
  } else {
    // return promises but how?
   //if I simply do res.json(payment) it's not going to work.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some concepts wrong.

The server response can not be a Promise, since it's already outside the scope of Javascript. In this case we are already speaking about HTTP requests.
The type of the response is specified in the header [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type), the types available can be checked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types).

In your code you are using `json.res()`, so you will be sending back to the client a text in JSON format.

If you want to get the response from the server through Promises, that must be implemented in the client.